# How to customize firebase auth ui

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-spinner, firebaseui

I am using Firebase Auth Ui from number verification. I have some requirements where i need to change text and background color of country spinner's dropdown item. I am using this below style but it doesn't change the color of dropdown's background or item's text color.

```
style name="FirebaseUI.CountrySpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorVerifyButtonText</item>
</style>
```

What am i doing wrong here, please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to extend the FirebaseUI theme and pass that into the builder options.
Example:

```
<style name="GreenTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <!-- Required for sign-in flow styling -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_green_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_purple_a700</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/material_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/material_lime_a700</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/material_green_a200</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_green_50</item>
</style>
```

And in Java:

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance(this).createSignInIntentBuilder()
        // ...
        .setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme)
        .build());
```

And the docs: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#themes

You'll basically want to extend the FirebaseUI style with your drop-down attribute.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know how to customize Firebase UI.

Comment: It does, that's how you customize FirebaseUI . Please read my response.

Comment: You want to style drop downs, right? Especially the country list one. The only way to style that stuff without overriding the layout file is by passing in a custom style to the FirebaseUI builder.

Comment: That's what i am doing and it is not effect. Check that xml style that i wrote.

Comment: No, you need to add a single style element which extends the FirebaseUI one and has just the drop down attribute.

Comment: did you figure out why the dropdown color wouldn't change?