# How to customize specific element in Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to customize the firebase AuthUI interface in order for it to fit with my background image.

Partially , I solved the problem using the solution provided here: [How to customize firebase auth ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192361/how-to-customize-firebase-auth-ui/61160885?noredirect=1#comment108198379_61160885)

Unfortunatelly , I can't find the attribute I need to modify in order to modify the color of the text in the Number Authentification function?(The one that says "By tapping "Verify Phone Number" ... ")

Can somebody help me with the name of the attribute I need to modify? I am developing an Android app in Android Studio using Kotlin.

Comment: It might be helpful if you also say which client platform you're using.

Comment: I am developing an Android app in Android Studio using Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Since the firebase-auth-ui is just an [open source project](https://firebaseopensource.com/) by the Google its source code is provided on Github. So, the best way to your problem would be to pull/clone the github repository of firebase-auth-ui for app (Android I am assuming).

The link to their repository is : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth/app

Just clone it or download zip file of it. Change it according to your own UI needs and then upload it to github or directly link it to your project.

The process is long but will assure you a quality app.

Comment: The question is asking for the name of the property to modify to style the provided UI.  It's not asking how to build Firebase UI to customize its code.